# How to recreate an ATR file after it was deleted from the catalog in the file system?

Tags: catalog, obiee

How can I recreate the .atr file for a folder in OBIEE?
On the server, the catalog contains a directory, but its corresponding ATR file is missing.

As a result, the folder does not appear in the UI.

It was inadvertently deleted from the file system.

Can I reverse engineer the ATR using another ATR file, or does the Catalog Manager application have a utility to help restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reverse-engineering the ATR file, let the Catalog rebuild it automatically by re-propagating folder permissions down from a higher folder level in the catalog.

After this, the missing folder (caused by the missing ATR file) will now appear in the BI Catalog.

Comment: Answered my own question later that day.